# Update multiple rows to their unique id with one value changed in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have below Array (50 elements in this array. so below mysql query fires 50 times.) to update in DB

```
$array = [['id'=>1,'result'=>'21.25'],['id'=>2,'result'=>'13.03']]// ... up to 50 elements in this array. so below mysql query fires 50 times.
```

And I am doing like this.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $postArray =  ['result' => $value['result']];
    DB::table('table')->where('id',$value['id'])->update($postArray);
}
```

**Question : Is it possible to merge all in one query ?**

I tried like this but not working,

```
giving error `"errormsg":"Database error!! preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string
```

while replacement is an array"`

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $postArray[] =  [
        'id' => $value['id'],
        'result' => $value['result']
    ];
}
DB::table('table')->update($postArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereIn() function to update multiple row with same data.

```
$idArray = array(1, 2, 3);
$postArray =  ['result' => $value['result']];
DB::table('table')->whereIn('id',$idArray)->update($postArray);
```

Note: From code syntax, I have assumed you are using Laravel framework. So solution applies to Laravel. If you are using other framework, you can check similar method for it.

Comment: his case was perform updates for 50 unique id with 50 new data. Not 50 id for 1 new data